# Getting an Android Activity To Run Non-Activity Code

Tags: android, class, google-maps, android-activity

I have an android app that basically just plots points on a map.
These maps are determined from a totally different class.
I originally wrote this class as its own program (it reads a CSV file and picks out points and gives back their longitude and latitude in an array).

So, what I have done is added this class to my Android App program.  I want the app at some point to call up the class's method that will generate the array, return it, and use this new array to plot points on the map.  As far as grabbing the array and pinpointing each of their latitudes and longitudes goes, I can do it.

However, when in my Android App's main class, I state:

```
String[][] bump = ReadCsv.getArray(fileToUse);
```

, my program will force close.  (ReadCsv is the name of the class I put in the program - getArray in the only method in the class, and it returns an array[][]).

Does anyone think they see what my problem here is?  Maybe an alternative solution is possible?

The LogCat is shown below:

> 07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:86)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   07-27 15:19:25.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12214):     ... 11 more

And my code is:

```
package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
MapView mapView; 
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
GeoPoint p2;
GeoPoint p99;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    mapView.setSatellite(true);

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {"42.30936432", "-71.12162781"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(8); 

    //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    //listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay); 

    // -- my own point ---
    String coordinates2[] = {"42.20", "-71.20"};
    double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates2[0]);
    double lng2 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates2[1]);
    p2 = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat2 * 1E6),
            (int) (lng2 * 1E6));
    MapOverlay mapOverlay2 = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays2 = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays2.add(mapOverlay2);

    // Add points from ReadCsv.java
    File fileToUse = new File("/Users/csrobot/Desktop/Training4.csv");
    String[][] bump = ReadCsv.getArray(fileToUse);
    for(int i = 0; i < bump.length; i++) {
        String coordinates99[] = {bump[i][0], bump[i][1]};
        double lat99 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates99[0]);
        double lng99 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates99[1]);
        p99 = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (lat99 * 1E6),
                (int) (lng99 * 1E6));
        MapOverlay mapOverlay99 = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays99 = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays99.add(mapOverlay99);
    } 

    mapView.invalidate();
}

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.redpin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-44, null);         


        // --make my own point---
        Point screenPts2 = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p2, screenPts2);
        Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.redpin);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, screenPts2.x, screenPts2.y-44, null);


        return true;
    }
} 

static class ReadCsv {

    public static String[][] getArray(File file) {

        try {
                   //
                   // Code That I know Works is Here
                   //
            return arrayOfBumps;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
                  // System.out.println("The following error occurred "+e);
        }
        return null;

    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

EDIT:  For Ravi Bhatt

```
private class MapPoint extends AsyncTask <String[][], String, String> {

    @Override  
    protected String doInBackground(String[][]... <<What goes here...? >>) {

    String << what am i making to return? >> = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("Training4.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        bump = getArray(reader);
        if(bump == null){
                setContentView(R.layout.deleteme);
            } else {
                for(int i = 0; i < bump.length; i++) {
                    String coordinates99[] = {bump[i][0], bump[i][1]};
                    double lat99 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates99[0]);
                    double lng99 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates99[1]);
                    p99 = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (lat99 * 1E6),
                        (int) (lng99 * 1E6));
                    MapOverlay mapOverlay99 = new MapOverlay();
                    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays99 = mapView.getOverlays();
                    listOfOverlays99.add(mapOverlay99);
                } 
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return << do I really need to return something? if so, what? >>;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mapView.refreshDrawableState();

}

}
```

Comment: Whenever an application "force closes", it will generally have some error information available in logcat.  Please include that information in your post, otherwise, it's anyone's guess as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best think for your needs is AsyncTask.
use this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

you can pass params in **doInBackground()** methods. params can be the list of latitude and longitude.

-- make geopoing

-- create overlayitem

-- add it in itemized overlay

**onPostExectute()** method do following.

-- add it in to mapoverlay i.e. list of overlay.
-- you can use refreshdrawablestate() method after that.

for putting that overlay from non activity class you can use mapactivity's reference or context and use it for adding the overlay.

**EDIT :**

for example, consider the example mapview from the link http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

When using AsncTask, as you have array of coordinates, pass this array in AsyncTask as params like AsyncTask.

then **doInBackGround()** method use ***doInBackGroud < String[][]...varName >*** as you have string array. Put that for loop logic to derive coordinates and Geopoint in doInBackGround Method.

--add each of the overlayitem which u get from coordinate in itemizedOverlay (as per link of hello mapview).

--In **onPostExecute()**  method add that itemized overlay in the List of the map and use mapview.refreshdrawablestate(). you can use onPostExecute with declaration like ***onPostExecute(Void result)***

Do the above step with understanding and its DONE!!! :)

Comment: It JUST about makes sense to me!  However, I'm a little confused about a few things.  Could you take a look at the new section of code I posted at the bottom of my question for me, and tell me what I might have done wrong/should be doing?

Comment: in doInBackground() method's params give any name for that String[][] array which you can later use for getting the geopoints or cordinates.

Comment: in doInBackground() method's params give any name for that String[][] array which you can later use for getting the geopoints or cordinates. and in return statement of this method return anything like return "done.." or anything..its not important

Comment: I got it now and it works!  I'm able to see the map and scroll through it until the program has finished and plotted the GeoPoints on the map.  Now I actually have a new question :x.  Why is my map unbearably laggy after the GeoPoint has been mapped?  Is there some process I need to kill or something along those lines once all the points have been mapped so the program stops lagging?

Comment: add list of overlays on map in onPostExecution method like 
                    listOfOverlays99.add(mapOverlay99);
and then use refreshdrawablestate if needed.

Comment: i did not get what do you mean by laggy or laggin? can you describe it please.

Comment: To lag = to run really slow.  So after the points are plotted, the map takes a really long time to respond to user interactions (like zooming, scrolling around, etc.).

Comment: i have tried it with few plotted points so i havent faced any problem like that. i am sorry i dont know why it happens with your app. :( may be bcoz there are much plotted points.

Comment: I actually only have 16 points to be plotted, but only one is plotting as well :x

Comment: make ArrayList of OverlayItem and by using geopoint add each item into it in the doInBackGround() and add that array in List of overlay into onPostExecution() method. Refer Hello-Mapview example of developer.android.com for that

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons you are seeing a force close.  Have you tried stepping into the main method and seeing where it crashes?  You might be using the parameter for something that is causing the crash when you pass null. ie were you passing the filename to use in your stand alone app?

This type of operation is typically not done inside an activity since it would make your app's UI janky.  I would investigate IntentService and call your code from it.  You can then invoke the IntentService whenever you want from your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it from Source or a Jar file?  If you're using it as a Jar file it could be dying because your program uses an API not available to Android.  The other option might be it touches the args.  I'd try passing ReadCSV.main(new String[] {}).

I see a java.lang.NullPointerException, but looking through the logcat is hard because of formatting.  But Something inside ReadCSV is throwing a NPE.  I'd suggest step through ReadCSV with a debugger, or find the line number of the line that's tossing that NPE.  Actually found it:

net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:81)

So on line 81 in MapsActivity is the problem.  It doesn't look like ReadCSV.main() is being reached yet.

I would also follow the suggestion of doing this inside a AsyncTask.  Even I'd consider factoring out all of your code into a proper method that you can directly invoke and return the Array directly because ReadCSV.main() is a void return type.  So what it produces must be a file or something so you can get that data.  Instead of that just have it return a plain array.  Something like:

```
public List<Row> readCSV( File f ) {
}
```

That's what you could do to make this easier on yourself.

Comment: I actually did change it up so that its all in one class, and now returns an array.  However, I'm still getting a force close with the same error.  Give me a minute to post my new code.

Comment: I don't think it's your code in ReadCSV that's the problem.  From the look of it MapsActivity.onCreate() method line 81 is where the problem is.  MapsActivity is outside your ReadCSV class so it's not involved, unless it's returning null.

Comment: This is line 81: listOfOverlays2.add(mapOverlay2);  It worked before I tried implementing the ReadCSV class in.. so I'm still in doubt that that's the problem, unless you think it's causing a problem.